# "X" is a namespace but it is used like a type error in C# Visual Code Studio

Tags: c#, .net

I know there are a few answers for this question but I looked at them and still can't make sense of it :(

First script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace IT05032_MyCodeSnippet. HelloWorld
{
    public class Hello
    {
        public String GetHello()
        {
            return "Hello world!";
        }
    }
}
// Error: The type or namespace name 'Hello' could CS0246 not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) The type or namespace name 'Hello' could CS0246 not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Second script:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        //ViewBag. Message = "Your application description page.";
        Hello hello = new Hello();
        ViewBag.Message = hello.GetHello();
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag. Message = "Your contact page.";
        return View();
    }
}
// Error: Error: CS0246: Description The type or namespace name 'Hello' could CS0246 not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I'm trying to follow a walkthrough that my uni set (note, this is not a tutorial question or exam question) but it fails to explain why the namespace error needs to be resolved. Originally, as can be seen in the instructions, the error is "the type or namespace name Hello could not be found, are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" and when I restarted the program with no changes, it switched to the error in the title. Regardless, when I tried to compile it shows this:

[image]

I seriously don't get any of this and I feel sick, I've been reading all the material the uni provides me and this should be part of it but I have no idea what I'm even looking at. We get no C# training (these error riddled guides are all we get!) and are expected to make an entire project in 6 weeks (5 weeks left now). I feel like an idiot for even doing this degree because I seriously feel like I've learned nothing.

I followed the walkthrough provided by the uni. I'm not sure why they even excluded this if they weren't going to ask it as a question.

[image]

Comment: Did you add a `using` directive for the namespace of your Hello class to that controller? Which is exactly what that last step means

Comment: Please add your relevant code as formatted text to your question, as much as possible

Answer (score 1):

> In my HomeContoller.cs I need to resolve the namespace error.

We can see in your solution explorer that you have a file named `Hello.cs, presumably it has a class of the same name and is the first script included ion your post. We can also see that your controller that you are trying to instantiate this class from is in a different folder, but is following the default namespace convention where each folder is represented as a *dotted* part of the fully qualified class name:

- `HomeController`:
  `FIT5032_MyCodeSnippet.Controllers.HomeController`

Hello seems to be a manually constructed namespace and is not following the folder path convention:

- `Hello`:
  `IT05032_MyCodeSnippet.HelloWorld.Hello`

> **NOTE:** you can change these default by manually editing the namespaces in the code file. This convention is applied when the file is created, so if you create the files in one folder, then move those files around, they may not follow this convention. There are some plugins and techniques that can *fix* the namespaces after move operations, that is out of scope for this post, but be aware of it, don't just assume the namespaces, you may need to peek into the class files to look them up.

Think of a *namespace* as a logical grouping of code. When we want to reference classes outside of the current namespace we need to either fully declare the namespace in the class reference or we can add a *using statement* in the code file that tells the compiler to lookup specific namespaces to determine the specific classes and types we might be referencing in the code file.

To fix the issue in this case, you can add this directive to the top of your code file, you should see other _using _ statements, most probably `using System;`, put this up there:

```
using IT05032_MyCodeSnippet.HelloWorld;
```

How do you know when a namespace or using statements is required? Basically, you can reference any classes in the same namespace, as well as any unique classes in the parent levels of the same namespace.

So from your controller you can reference any classes in the following namespaces, without a using statement or fully qualifying them:

- `FIT5032_MyCodeSnippet.Controllers`
- `FIT5032_MyCodeSnippet`

Keep in mind that namespaces are *logical* grouping, it has nothing to do with the physical folder of file the code is defined in.

A *using statement* is only really a *hint*. If there was a `Hello` class in both of those namespaces, then the reference would be ambiguous and the compiler would require us to fully define the class name.

For your `Hello` class, we can use it's full name instead of a *using statement*:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    //ViewBag. Message = "Your application description page.";
    IT05032_MyCodeSnippet.HelloWorld.Hello hello = new IT05032_MyCodeSnippet.HelloWorld.Hello();
    ViewBag.Message = hello.GetHello();
    return View();
}
```

You will quickly learn to love this error, but the answer is in the error itself:

> The type or namespace name 'Hello' could CS0246 not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

We have covered the *using directive* which is the most common way to fix this, but if there was no class in your project called `Hello` then the only other way for your code to be correct is if the class is defined in a different project or dll that you have forgotten to add as a reference to this project.

- Spelling mistakes and case sensitivity are often the reason for the error, the compiler assumes you know what you are doing and is too polite to tell you to check the spelling... `Hello` might not exist at all ;)